# Vue.js toggle class on click

Tags: css, vue.js

How does toggle a class in vue.js?

I have the following:

```
<th class="initial " v-on="click: myFilter">
    <span class="wkday">M</span>
</th>

new Vue({
  el: '#my-container',
  data: {},
  methods: {
    myFilter: function(){
      // some code to filter users
    }
  }
});
```

When I click `<th>` tag I want to apply `active` as a class as follows:

```
<th class="initial active" v-on="click: myFilter">
    <span class="wkday">M</span>
</th>
```

This needs to toggle i.e. each time its clicked it needs to add/remove the class.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You could have the active class be dependent upon a boolean data value:

```
<th 
  class="initial " 
  v-on="click: myFilter"
  v-class="{active: isActive}">
  <span class="wkday">M</span>
</th>

new Vue({
  el: '#my-container',

  data: {
    isActive: false
  },

  methods: {
    myFilter: function() {
      this.isActive = !this.isActive;
      // some code to filter users
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: for some reason `v-class="active: isActive"` crashes my app, but `v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }" ` works for me.  Hope this is helpful for someone.

Comment: My example is from version 0.12

Comment: syntax seems to change all the time with vue. In 2.* you can also just do `:class="..."`

Comment: I am doing it in vue.js-2. When I click on one row, the `active` class is being applied to all the rows. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you can make each row its own component that is responsible for its own `isActive` property

Comment: all of the examples for setting an Active class are for just one item, what if I had multiple I v-for rendered, how then would I impart Active class on the most recently clicked of this list. 

`<a href="#" @click="switchRoom(room)" class="rooms" :class="{currentRoom: room.isActive}" v-for="(room, index) in allRooms" :key="index">{{ room.name }} </a>`

Comment: looks like I can't use double hyphen in my class name with this method? for example `:class="{ click--butonClass: ifTrue }"`

Comment: If the class name has a hyphen => `v-bind:class="{ 'active-class': isActive }"`

Comment: `v-class`? Never heard of that one and cannot find it back in the API. I doubt this is still relevant as a possible solution. Prefer using `:class` for sure.

Comment: @kissu - as mentioned, my example is from version 0.12 (This is a pretty old question)

Answer (score 108):

Without the need of a method:

```html
<!-- html element, will display'active' class if showMobile is true -->
<!-- clicking on the elment will toggle showMobileMenu to true and false alternatively -->
<div id="mobile-toggle"
  :class="{ active: showMobileMenu }"
  @click="showMobileMenu = !showMobileMenu">
</div>
```

`vue.js app`

```js
data: {
  showMobileMenu: false
}
```

Comment: @ConnorLeech `<li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id" 
            v-bind:class="{ active: active == item }" 
            @click="active = item">`
Then add `.active {styles}` and put it within `<ul>`

Comment: And what is active? `showMobileMenu` is a variable but what is the class?

Comment: @rjurney `active` is the CSS class. Better written this way: `'active': showMobileMenu`, but it's the same thing.

Comment: Nice solution.  I've been using ternary expressions to do this and this is so much cleaner.

Answer (score 62):

If you don't need to access the toggle from outside the element, this code works without a data variable:

```
<a @click="e => e.target.classList.toggle('active')"></a>
```

Comment: Wanted this. Simple & general.

Comment: I am kinda new to Vue but there is a problem I encountered with this solution. When I add  @click="e => e.target.classList.toggle('active')" on vue-bootstrap card parent element what happens is that the whole card doesn't get the CSS toggle, instead the class applies on parts of card you click and you can toggle multiple in a single card.

Comment: @Kevz that is indeed a limitation of this approach - it only toggles the event target, which is the most nested <a> or <button> you click on. For your problem I would instead use one of the data variable solutions on this page.

Comment: You can add `parentNode` after `target` if you don't mind Vue's quirk of toggling the class on both elements. I found adding `pointer-events: none` to the child element's CSS easiest.

Answer (score 28):

This answer relevant for `Vue.js version 2`

```html
<th 
  class="initial " 
  v-on:click="myFilter"
  v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }"
>
  <span class="wkday">M</span>
</th>
```

The rest of the answer by Douglas is still applicable (setting up the new Vue instance with `isActive: false`, etc).

Relevant docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax and https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers

Comment: when I click on one row, the `active` class is being applied to all the rows. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: same problem here, this only works if there is only one clickable element in the component. what if a component has several clickable elements?

Comment: If you ask a new question I can look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 21):

This example is using Lists: When clicking in some li it turn red

**html:**

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li @click="activate(li.id)" :class="{ active : active_el == li.id }" v-for="li in lista">{{li.texto}}</li>   
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    lista:[{"id":"1","texto":"line 1"},{"id":"2","texto":"line 2"},{"id":"3","texto":"line 3"},{"id":"4","texto":"line 4"},{"id":"5","texto":"line 5"}],
    active_el:0
  },
  methods:{
    activate:function(el){
        this.active_el = el;
    }
  }
});
```

**css**

```
ul > li:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}
.active {
  color:red;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/w37vLL68/158/

Comment: Thank you very much, This helped me.

Answer (score 16):

1. 

```
@click="$event.target.classList.toggle('active')"
```

2. 

```
:class="{ active }"
@click="active = !active"
```

3. 

```
:class="'initial ' + (active ? 'active' : '')"  
@click="active = !active"
```

4. 

```
:class="['initial', { active }]"  
@click="active = !active"
```

Reference link: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

**Demo:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app1'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app2',
  data: { active: false }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app3',
  data: { active: false }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app4',
  data: { active: false }
});
```

```css
.initial {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<!-- directly manipulation: not recommended -->
<div id="app1">
    <button 
      class="initial"  
      @click="$event.target.classList.toggle('active')"
    >$event.target.classList.toggle('active')</button>
</div>

<!-- binding by object -->
<div id="app2">
    <button 
      class="initial"  
      :class="{ active }"
      @click="active = !active"
    >class="initial" :class="{ active }"</button>
</div>

<!-- binding by expression -->
<div id="app3">
    <button 
      :class="'initial ' + (active ? 'active' : '')"  
      @click="active = !active"
    >'initial ' + (active ? 'active' : '')</button>
</div>

<!-- binding with object combined array -->
<div id="app4">
    <button 
      :class="['initial', { active }]"  
      @click="active = !active"
    >['initial', { active }]</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

In addition to NateW's answer, if you have hyphens in your css class name, you should wrap that class within (single) quotes:

```html
<th 
  class="initial " 
  v-on:click="myFilter"
  v-bind:class="{ 'is-active' : isActive}"
>
  <span class="wkday">M</span>
</th>
```

See [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/v-bindclass-has-problem-with-hyphenated-class-names) topic for more on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

**If you need more than 1 class**

You can do this:

```
<i id="icon" 
  v-bind:class="{ 'fa fa-star': showStar }"
  v-on:click="showStar = !showStar"
  >
</i> 

data: {
  showStar: true
}
```

Notice the single quotes ' around the classes!

Thanks to everyone else's solutions.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you would achieve that one with Vue3 + Composition API

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
  
const isTextRed = ref(false)
function toggleClass() {
  isTextRed.value = !isTextRed.value
}
</script>

<template>
  <h1 :class="isTextRed && 'fancy-color'">Hi community </h1>
  <button @click="toggleClass">Toggle color</button>
</template>

<style scoped>
.fancy-color {
  color: coral;  
}
</style>
```

Here is [a playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNpdUUtuwjAQvcrUCwJSScQ2DagVm64rlt4E44Cpf7IntAjlBF1UPQEH6aU4QseJ1EbdzRu/9/xm5sKevM9PrWQlq6IIyiNEia1fcauMdwHhAkE20EETnIGMqBm3ANwKZyOCihv5ji9yB8vEmza1jnLGbdNagcpZQLffa7nWdYzTGVyS9leTn2rdSlLe/Wtx23FbFUMgikIApfG6RkkIoDosoBTJc8nZX4TJBLKmtuI8F067kHG2elYgnDGtVXiG2/Xr43b9/K6Kw2Lw2baIFPJRaCVeyWuUlsSbHpEBmVXFwCVdVYzCEIx4JlYUzssddfJRhGHgvixh7UKtH9LuhumSbMXu2bDoual9fozO0il6FU3WP1CScvBJPTpAwpwdEH0siyI2Ih3wGHMX9gVVeWgtKiNzGc18G9xblIGMOUsW9HPHuh8HZrLw).

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution that allows you to check for different values of a prop and thus different `<th>` elements will become active/inactive. Using vue 2 syntax.

```
<th 
class="initial " 
@click.stop.prevent="myFilter('M')"
:class="[(activeDay == 'M' ? 'active' : '')]">
<span class="wkday">M</span>
</th>
...
<th 
class="initial " 
@click.stop.prevent="myFilter('T')"
:class="[(activeDay == 'T' ? 'active' : '')]">
<span class="wkday">T</span>
</th>



new Vue({
  el: '#my-container',

  data: {
      activeDay: 'M'
  },

  methods: {
    myFilter: function(day){
        this.activeDay = day;
      // some code to filter users
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

for nuxt link and bootstrap v5 navbar-nav, I used a child component

```
             <nuxt-link
              @click.prevent.native="isDropdwonMenuVisible = !isDropdwonMenuVisible"
              to=""
              :title="item.title"
              :class="[item.cssClasses, {show: isDropdwonMenuVisible}]"
              :id="`navbarDropdownMenuLink-${index}`"
              :aria-expanded="[isDropdwonMenuVisible ? true : false]"
              class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
              aria-current="page"
              role="button"
              data-toggle="dropdown"
            >
              {{ item.label }}
            </nuxt-link>

data() {
    return {
      isDropdwonMenuVisible: false
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a prop, you can alternatively call the data into another data variable set using an axios response or any other way you use to pull data into a specified vue component.

You can modify the number 32 below in all places to change the length of text you want to display before and after selecting more/less.

Works with Vue2 & Vue3.

"fw-bold" is a Bootstrap 5 class. It has no affect on this implementation.

```
props: {
        content: Object,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            // UX
            showComplete: false,
            // DATA
            shortText: "",
            longText: "",
        };
    },
    methods: {
        shortenText(body) {
            const length = body.length;
            if (length >= 32) {
                this.shortText = body.slice(0, 32);
                this.longText = body.slice(32, -1);
            }
        },
        toggleFull() {
            this.showComplete = !this.showComplete;
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.shortenText(this.content.body);
    },
```

In the vue template simply do this:

```
<span>{{ shortText }}</span>
<span v-if="showComplete">{{ longText }}</span>
<span v-if="!showComplete" class="fw-bold" @click="toggleFull"> more...</span>
<span v-if="showComplete" class="fw-bold" @click="toggleFull"> less...</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#fsbar',
  data:{
    isActive: false
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(){
      this.isActive = !this.isActive;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/*
    DEMO STYLE
*/
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";


body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

i, span {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header h3, #sidebar.active .CTAs {
    display: none;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header strong {
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    text-align: left;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a i {
    margin-right:  0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#sidebar.active ul ul a {
    padding: 10px !important;
}

#sidebar.active a[aria-expanded="false"]::before, #sidebar.active a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
    display: none;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}
#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #7386D5;
    background: #fff;
}
#sidebar ul li a i {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li.active > a, a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}


a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

a[aria-expanded="false"]::before, a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: '\e259';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 0.6em;
}
a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: '\e260';
}


ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}

a.article, a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}



/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */
#content {
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        min-width: 80px;
        max-width: 80px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: -80px !important ;
    }
    a[aria-expanded="false"]::before, a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
        top: auto;
        bottom: 5px;
        right: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
        transform: translateX(50%);
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }

    #sidebar .sidebar-header h3, #sidebar .CTAs {
        display: none;
    }

    #sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
        display: block;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a {
        padding: 20px 10px;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a span {
        font-size: 0.85em;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a i {
        margin-right:  0;
        display: block;
    }

    #sidebar ul ul a {
        padding: 10px !important;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a i {
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <title>Collapsible sidebar using Bootstrap 3</title>

         <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style4.css">
    </head>
    <body>



        <div class="wrapper" id="fsbar">
            <!-- Sidebar Holder -->
            <nav id="sidebar" :class="{ active: isActive }">
                <div class="sidebar-header">
                    <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
                    <strong>BS</strong>
                </div>

                <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
                            Home
                        </a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                            <li><a href="#">Home 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Home 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Home 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i>
                            About
                        </a>
                        <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"></i>
                            Pages
                        </a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></i>
                            Portfolio
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></i>
                            FAQ
                       isActive: false, </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i>
                            Contact
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
                    <li><a href="https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/files/sidebar.zip" class="download">Download source</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar" class="article">Back to article</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <!-- Page Content Holder -->
            <div id="content">

                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="container-fluid">

                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn" @click="toggle()">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i>
                                <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

                <h2>Collapsible Sidebar Using Bootstrap 3</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <div class="line"></div>

                <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <div class="line"></div>

                <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <div class="line"></div>

                <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>





        <!-- jQuery CDN -->
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
         <!-- Bootstrap Js CDN -->
         <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        /<script type="text/javascript">
         //    $(document).ready(function () {
          //       $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
           //          $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
            //     });
            // }); jquery equivalent to vue
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
<template>
   <th :class="'initial '+ active" v-on="click: myFilter">
       <span class="wkday">M</span>
   </th>  
</template>

<script lang="ts">

    active:string=''
    myFilter(){
       this.active='active'
    }
</script>

<style>
  .active{
     /***your action***/
   }

</style>
```

Comment: Apart from a code snippet, please add a brief explanation of why this solves the issue.

Comment: This code snippet simply doesn't work too tbh.