# Vue.js: How to change a class when a user has clicked on a link?

Tags: css, vue.js

I am trying to add a class to an element depending on whether the user has clicked on a link. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731939/vue-js-toggle-class-on-click) but it is not working as I wanted it to be.

I created a component which has its own internal data object which has the property, `isShownNavigation: false`. So when a user clicks on the `a` I change `isShownNavigation: true` and expect my css class `isClicked` to be added. Alas that is not happening - `isShownNavigation` stays `false` in the component when I displayed it `{{isShownNavigation}}` but I can see in the console that my method is working when clicked.

I imported my `header` component to the `App`. Code is below.

**Header Component**

```
<template>
<header class="header">
  <a 
    href="#"
    v-bind:class="{isClicked: isShowNavigation}"
    v-on:click="showNavigation">
    Click
  </a>
</header>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'header-component',
  methods: {
    showNavigation: () => {
      this.isShowNavigation = !this.isShowNavigation
    }
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      isShowNavigation: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Application**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <header-component></header-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HeaderComponent from './components/Header.vue'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    'header-component': HeaderComponent
  }
}
</script>
```

I am using the pwa template from https://github.com/vuejs-templates/pwa.

Thanks.

Comment: You can just use CSS `a:visited` selector to style it if the link is clicked(visited).

Comment: I wanted to add a css class somewhere else which is not on the `a`. I used adding it to the `a` for simplicity.

Comment: 0h k then. Anyhow u got your answer from Bert Evans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use fat arrow functions to define your methods, data, computed, etc. When you do, `this` will not be bound to the Vue. Try

```
export default {
  name: 'header-component',
  methods: {
    showNavigation(){
      this.isShowNavigation = !this.isShowNavigation
    }
  },
  data(){
    return {
      isShowNavigation: false
    }
  }
}
```

See [VueJS: why is “this” undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929650)? In this case, you could also really just get rid of the showNavigation method and set that value directly in your template if you wanted to.

```
<a 
  href="#"
  v-bind:class="{isClicked: isShowNavigation}"
  v-on:click="isShowNavigation = true">
  Click
</a>
```

Finally, if/when you end up with more than one link in your header, you will want to have a clicked property associated with each link, or an active link property instead of one global clicked property.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. I have a navigation `div` to which I will be adding the class and not on the `a`. I have used `a` for simplicity. There is a good answer https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-make-a-component-with-menu-item-changing-css-to-active-when-clicked/3235 on how to do it if you want to add styles to different navigation links. It is an interesting approach.

Comment: You can definitely rely on answers from @LinusBorg :) He is a core member of the Vue team. He answers questions here as well.